# It's possible to set HTTP headers with htaccess?

Tags: http, header, http-headers

i have website on PHP and i wont to know how to set this HTTP headers:

- Last-Modified
- If-Modified-Since
- Cache-Control
- ETag

**For Last-Modified i try this:**

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
```

**For Cache-Control:**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|pdf)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate" 
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate" 
</FilesMatch>
```

**For ETag this:**

```
Header unset
ETag File
ETag None
```

But don't works and don't returned in headers. It's right method with htaccess, it's possible? In case of YES, how to make it?

Thank you so much on advise!

Comment: Share what you tried so far. If it didn't work, it might be easier to help people figure out what went wrong.

Comment: **For Last-Modified i try this:**
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}] 
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]

**For Cache-Control:**
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|pdf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>


**For ETag this:**
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

But don't works and don't returned in headers.